# Find all the methods that are called when POST a form in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is there a way to get all the methods that are called and executed ( Even the methods from the external libraries) when POST -ing to a Controller.

Example:

In Laravel, when you POST to a postLogin Controller all methods from the external library for the authentication are called in order to Authenticate the user.

What I need is names of all methods that are involved.

Comment: Use a code profiler (e.g. Blackfire.io or the one built in with xdebug), that'll tell you everything that's called

Comment: To my knowledge if you throw an exception and debug is turned on it will show the entire stacktrace which includes every method it hits.

Comment: What are you looking for?

Comment: Thank you for your answers guys. I have the following scenario: I'm trying to authenticate users with LDAP and I'm doing some checks in postLogin Controller ( Laravel 5.1), but these checks are skipped and the first class that is called is LdapAuthManager. Strange, because I'm posting the form to postLogin Controller...